# Error 'The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found...' in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, using-directives, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro:

> CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

I'm pretty sure the Xamarin code was working 1½ years ago but it was on my old Dell computer running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Pro.

What does the `using Android.App` do?
I tried to remove it, but that didn't help, it just produced the following error:

> XA5104: Could not locate the Android NDK. Please make sure the Android NDK is installed in the Android SDK Manager, or if using a custom NDK path, please ensure the $(AndroidNDKDirectory) MSBuild property is set to the custom path.

[image: XA5104]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can recheck if you have set the Android NDK Location correctly. For more, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location?tabs=windows .

Comment: hi, Have you found a solution to the problem ?